# Invoking default methods from lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is there a way to invoke a default method when defining lambda?

E.g.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface StringCombiner {
    String combine(String s1, String s2);

   default String bar(String s1, String s2) {
        return combine(s1,s2);
   };

}
```

I want to make something like this:

```
StringCombiner sc = (s1, s2) -> /** I want to call bar() here **/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would lead to a StackOverflowError : `bar` calls `combine`, which calls `bar`, which calls `combine`...

You need to recursively refer to `sc` in its definition (you can't use `this` in a lambda to refer to the object being created by the lambda). I believe that is only possible in an instance or class variable. So it could look like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface StringCombiner {
    String combine(String s1, String s2);
    default String bar(String s1, String s2) { return "bar"; }
}

//Note: you need the static block to avoid a "self-reference" compilation error
static StringCombiner sc;
static {
  sc = (s1, s2) -> sc.bar(s1, s2) + s1 + s2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sc.combine("a", "b"));
}
```

which prints `barab`.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry yes, I forgot to remove invocation of combine from bar. This is however irrelevant here.
Anyway you've answered my question.
Thx! :)

Comment: doesn't work because of "self-reference in initalizer"

Comment: @mysh Indeed thanks - it compiled with earlier versions of Java 8 that were in use when I first posted the answer. With the latest version you need to split the declaration and the initialisation.